# Элемент находит, но клик не происходит java/selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

`JAVA\Selenium Web Driver`

Не происходит клик на элемент,но элемент на странице находит,так как он внизу страницы WD опускается к элементу,но клика не происходит

```
driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
```

Ошибка происходит уже на следующем клике,так как элемента на странице нет,из-за того что предыдущий клик не сработал.

В чём может быть причина? `Thread.sleep(5000);` убирал и ставил ничего не меняется

Пробовал `xpath` вместо `id`, но результата не дало

```
driver.findElement(By.id("add-description")).sendKeys("Продам собаку с родословной");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Не рекламировать")).click();
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть на страницу?

Comment: конечно можно,но здесь лимит- превышение допустимой длины на 3124 символа

Comment: используйте например [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)